# CADisplayLink Timestamp acts strange on device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, timer, cadisplaylink

For my game loop and certain animations I want to know the time interval that has passed since the last call of my render: method.

For this I use the CADisplayLink and grab the current timestamp and subtract the timestamp of the last call. This should give me the correct time interval between two frames/calls.

When running the app in the simulator, I get all sorts of different values for the interval, which seem fine. If I run the app on the iPad however, I only get two different values for the interval: 0.000 and 0.125. Most of the time these two values alternate.

Here is the code I use to determine the interval.

```
// Time calculations (for animations and stuff)
_lastCallTime = _currentCallTime;
_currentCallTime = [displayLink timestamp];
float timeInterval = _currentCallTime - _lastCallTime;

NSLog(@"Time since last call: %f", timeInterval);
```

This code gets executed every time the render method gets called.

Is this some restriction of the iPad, that it won't give me accurate results for my interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timestamp is a double. Change any variable that saves or uses it as a float to NSTimeInterval. When you print it use %f (which is really %lf as C promotes floats to doubles when passed as parameters).